# Итерация на 0.25

Tags: javascript

Как можно произвести итерацию с увеличением значения переменной не в 1, а в 0.25 ?
Например,

```
numberDetails.val(0.25);
var qty = numberDetails.val();
qty++;
```

И на выходе в консоли qty выводит:

```
1.25, 2.25, 3.25...
```

Ожидаемый результат:

```
0.5, 0.75, 1,
```

Comment: foo = foo + 0.25 - не?

Comment: `qty += 0.25;` тогда уж.

Comment: @Regent, да, точно. тупанул, + прикрутил преобразование в строку parseFloat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
numberDetails.val(0.25);
var qty = parseFloat(numberDetails.val());
qty += 0.25;
```

Comment: нолик ещё убрать слева от запятой и будет по красоте

Comment: @Lexx918 а это весьма субъективно... Я вот наоборот за явное присутствие нуля.

Comment: Там может быть проблема если придет строка. Не очень понятно что такое `numberDetails.val()`, но могу предположить, что это получения `value` у инпута в jQuery. Если так, то строка там может быть вообще запросто. В таком случае лучше обернуть присвоение значения в `parseFloat` или хотя бы использовать унарный плюс.

Comment: Ну, по поводу 0 перед точкой дело субъективное (скорее всего он уберется при минификации), а на счет `parseFloat`  согласен, добавил. Спасибо за замечание.

Answer (score -2):

```
var qty = parseFloat(numberDetails.val()) || 0.25;
qty += qty;
```

Comment: А где увеличение на `0.25`? Вы же по-прежнему на единицу увеличиваете.

Comment: А где увеличение на 0.25? Вы в два раза увеличиваете.

Comment: Ну не, `qty += qty` - пожалуй, ещё хуже.

Comment: Если мой ответ помечен как верный, то комментарии не уместны.

Comment: @Kek и правда помечен, кликните по зеленой галочке что б убрать её.